# Find duplicate value in map using Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to write a program that finds the duplicate value in map, and this map is created using the list and utiity methods.

**I am able to get the expected output using for loop, but the code is too long using that.**

I tried using the java stream API as shown below, but got empty results.

```
public class PrintListElements {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add("1");
        roles.add("2");
        roles.add("3");
        roles.add("4");
        roles.add("5");
        roles.add("6");
        roles.add("7");
        roles.add("1");
        HashMap<String, List<String>> idToMap = new HashMap<>();
        roles.stream().map(role -> {
            if (idToMap.containsKey(role)) {
              return   idToMap.get(role).add(getName(role));
            } else {
                return idToMap.put(role, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getName(role))));
            }
        })

        idToMap.entrySet().forEach(e-> {
            if(e.getValue().size()>1) {
                System.out.println("found a key which has duplicate value : "+ e.getKey());
            }
        });

    }

    public static List<String> getNameLL(String id) {
        ArrayList<String> ll = new ArrayList<String>();
        ll.add(getName(id));
        return ll;
    }

    public static String getName(String id) {
        switch (id) {
            case "1":
                return "one";
            case "2":
                return "two";
            case "3":
                return "third";
            case "4":
                return "four";
            case "5":
                return "fifth";
            case "6":
                return "six";
            case "7":
                return "seven";
            case "8":
                return "one";
            default:
                return "one";
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
[one, one]
[two]
[three]
[four]
[five]
[six]
[seven]
```

**Can anyone please help me, to get the above-expected output result using Java Stream API**

Comment: `roles.stream().map(role -> {...` this piece of code will not get executed at all I think, can you please check Bhavya?

Comment: Your expected output is different from what you are actually willing to print. Do you really want to map to a `List<String>` value type in a `Map` or is the frequency of occurrence sufficient for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy` to group by key and use `Collectors.mapping` to map values and collect as a list for each key.

```
Map<String, List<String>> idToMap = 
    roles.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, 
                      Collectors.mapping(e -> getName(e), Collectors.toList())));
```

Or  `map` operation is lazy, so code inside `.map` is not executed. You can use terminal operation like `forEach` by refactoring your current code,

```
roles.forEach(role -> {
    if (idToMap.containsKey(role)) {
       idToMap.get(role).add(getName(role));
    } else {
       idToMap.put(role, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getName(role))));
    }
});
```

which can be simplified using `Map`'s `merge` method

```
roles.forEach(
    role -> idToMap.merge(role, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getName(role))), (a, b) -> {
      a.addAll(b);
      return a;
    }));
```

**Update:** If you want just print for duplicate value, you can use `Collectors.counting()` to get the frequency of key as a result collect as `Map<String, Integer>`

```
roles.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()))
     .entrySet()
     .forEach(e -> {
          if (e.getValue() > 1) {
            System.out.println("found a key which has duplicate value : " + e.getKey());
          }
      });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Can I also combine 

```idToMap.entrySet().forEach(e-> {
            if(e.getValue().size()>1) {
                System.out.println("found a key which has duplicate value : "+ e.getKey());
            }
        });``` 
with the 

```roles.stream().map()``` ?

Comment: Yes just add in chaining `roles.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.mapping(e -> getName(e), Collectors.toList()))).entrySet().forEach(...)`

Comment: the code you mentioned above..is working like a charm ..Can you please explain it briefly, and then I will accept the answer

Comment: @BhavyaGupta Can you say which part you don't understand ? I will try to explain about that :)

Comment: the first one, where you are using `Collectors.groupingBy`, but I think now its a bit clearer :) Accepted your answer :)